# Anaconda Navigator not launching Jupyter Notebook on MacBook

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I want to launch Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda Navigator but it just bring up some code on the terminal

I click launch and it brings these on the terminal

```
Last login: Tue Jul 25 10:59:45 on console
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
(base) Jafars-MacBook-Pro:~ jafarli-hammed$ /anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 81, in <module>
    from .services.contents.filemanager import FileContentsManager
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from send2trash import send2trash
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/send2trash/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .plat_osx import send2trash
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/send2trash/plat_osx.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .plat_osx_pyobjc import send2trash
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/send2trash/plat_osx_pyobjc.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Foundation import NSFileManager, NSURL
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/Foundation/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import CoreFoundation
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/CoreFoundation/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from CoreFoundation import _metadata
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/CoreFoundation/_metadata.py", line 43, in <module>
    "CFXMLAttributeDeclarationInfo": objc.createStructType(
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/objc/_structtype.py", line 45, in createStructType
    result = _orig_createStructType(name, typestr, fieldnames, doc, pack)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 1: invalid start byte
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command: line 5:  3566 Segmentation fault: 11  $DIR/jupyter-notebook
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...5 completed.

[Process completed]
```

Answer (score 0):

first make your conda environment available as a kernel

1. conda install -c conda-force ipykernel # installs ipykernel package
2. python -m ipykernel install --user --name=your_conda_env_name # links to your conda env
3. conda activate your_conda_env_name # activate your env
4. jupyter notebook # open jupyer notebook
5. from 'kernel' change the kernel to your 'your_conda_env_name'

[Linking the Conda Environment with Jupyter Notebook](https://saturncloud.io/blog/link-conda-environment-with-jupyter-notebook-a-stepbystep-guide-for-data-scientists/#linking-the-conda-environment-with-jupyter-notebook)